# Add a subview that is half the superview

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I created an xib, and the cs/designer.cs files following this:
https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/general/templates/using_the_ios_view_xib_template/

I can then create an instance of the xib view, and add it to another view.

So this works great, and adds the xib view.

I want to be able to change the frame, so that the xib view added only covers half the superview's width, like a sliding menu.

I can't change the Frame.Width property, as it is return only.

I added another view in storyboard that has the frames I want, and then assigned the xib view frame to that one and it still took up the whole view.

Any ideas or help are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frame.width is read only in both iOS and xamarin
The frame property isnt though.

I am porting the logic for updating frame in iOS, you can easily port it to xamarin

```
var frame = myView.frame
frame.size.width *= 0.5
myView.frame = frame;
```